# OpenNMS Spring Security LDAP Authentication not working

Tags: spring-security, ldap, opennms

I'm trying to configure OpenNMS to use LDAP authentication. I've configured Spring Security according to instructions from  https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/External_Authentication_Recipes. When I try to login with valid credentials I get the following error message:
[OpenNMS web UI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0DK7.png)

Comment: Did you check if `pluginManifestData.xml` exists in path `./etc`?

Comment: @thewaywewere It seems that the error from that log file is not related to my problem. When I tried again it didn't write anything in log files. I've edited the original post according to this.

Comment: Can you please click on the link in the error message and share with us the whole stack trace with the error message from your screenshot?

"To reveal details of the error ... click here"

Comment: It turned out that the cause of the problem was that the referral property was not set to _follow_. I've fixed that like this:
`<beans:property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
      <beans:map>
        <beans:entry key="java.naming.referral">
          <beans:value>follow</beans:value>
        </beans:entry>
      </beans:map>
    </beans:property>`